# What build orders work for the Training Day Achievment?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

What are the various build order's I can give that will allow me to complete this achievement?

> Train 10 Marines during the first 320 seconds of a single Melee game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
6 Supply Depot
6 Barracks
6 SCV
7 SCV
8 Barracks (first barracks is still being built use another SCV to do this)
```

Retask SCV's to mineral collection when they're done building

When the first barracks is finished start building marines in it (6-7 I think)
When the second barracks is finished build more marines out of it (3-4)

Comment: Remember you can SHIFT+RMB to queue the SCVs going back onto the mineral line after they've finished building.